# Postgresql 12 needs manual analyzing for performance

Tags: postgresql

I have a performance drop once in a couple of days. When I manually analyze a table, the performance is back to normal. The table to be analyzed has 2.7M records. The query is very complex, uses a lot of different tables, unions and joins. The view I query just aggregates some data from another view. If I query the main -aggregated- view, it takes about 1.5-3.5 secs. If I query the view one level higher, it takes only 0.2s.

This issue occured when migrated from 9.5 to 12.3. Analyzing one specific table solves it for a couple of days.

Autoanalyze never occurs automatically, so there seems no need to autoanalyze. But the query planner goes wrong somehow. I've increased the `statistics_target` in the config to 1500.

We never had this issue on 9.5. Maybe it has something to do with the JIT, but disabling it in the session does not seem to solve the issue.

Comment: "*Autoanalyze never occurs automatically,*" - that is your problem. You should investigate why this doesn't happen. More often than not long running `idle in transaction` sessions are the reason for that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't think it is. Idle transactions are rare in our setup. I've compared the postgresql.conf files, there are no differences on this part. The autoanalyze function only runs when a certain amount of data is changed, this will not happen in two or three days.

Comment: Then make auto-analyze more aggressive for that table (or in general)

Comment: It was something different: there were some tables in the queue for auto-analyzing, but they failed because of an error with the earthdistance module. Manual analyzing did work and I hope this fixes it permanently.